# C# WebAPI with Neo4j - Best Practice for Database connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, neo4j

this question is more about architecture than syntax.  I am building a WebAPI project in C# and I am using NEo4j, not SQL.  It seems to me I will be bypassing Entity Framework and any ORM and going directly to the DB (Is this assumption wrong?)   I am using the Neo4j library [here](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient). I anticipate a very high volume of traffic to the DB a vast majority of the traffic will be writes. Where is the best place to create my connection object within the MVC framework so I can limit the number of times I call client.connect()?  Thanks!

Comment: I'd think about wrapping this in its own assembly so the MVC app has no idea what the database technology is, and then I'd expose the necessary functionality (SaveThis, SaveThat, GeThis, etc.) via interfaces. This way if you need to change how you are dealing with connections, etc. it won't affect the client app.

Comment: For high volume writes please test upfront if the driver is up to your requirements, perhaps a WebRequest to the transactional Cypher endpoint would be faster, batching parametrized statements. And Neo4j 2.2 is much faster for concurrent writes btw.

Comment: After some time with the project I can say with a high level of confidence the Transactional Cypher Endpoint is robust enough for my needs

Answer (score 1):

I ultimately decided to use a helper class for GET web service calls and a cache between the Web Services and the DB. For POST web service calls I have implemented a Message queue and separate "DB Loader" service.  The lack of ORM has not had an effect on the project and using asynchronous method calls to the helper class and queue seem to have kept the performance at acceptable levels.